# How to better initialize strings to avoid dead stores

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsstring, dead-code

I found a few questions *like* this but I couldn't find this particular question. I have a number of strings that are initialized as

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

which are then assigned a value depending on the results of an if/else block:

```
if ([anotherThing isEqualToString:@"boogers"]) {
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some characters"];
} else {
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some _other_ characters"];
}
```

and then `string` is used later in the method.

How can I accomplish this without leaving a dead store at the alloc/init stage? If I alloc inside the if (or the else), the string is gone by the time I need it several lines down.

Comment: Why are you allocing and initing the "dead" string in the first place? Why not set it to `nil` since your execution path guarantees it will be assigned?

Comment: In addition to Joe Hankin's answer, if your strings don't need to be formatted, you can just use `string = @"some characters";`.

Comment: Thanks, @vcsjones. I didn't know you could do that.

@msoler, is there a good explanation somewhere on the real difference between `stringWithFormat:` and `stringWithString:`? I'm unsure how a formatted string differs from any others.

Comment: `stringWithFormat:` is for creating a string that includes the contents of variables, e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"There are %d states in %@", anInt, anotherString];`  `stringWithString:` is just a copy constructor.

Comment: @JoeHankin, thanks. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Check Apple's official doc about [formatting string objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) and [string format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to initialize the string on that first line -- you just need to declare it:

```
NSString *string = nil;
if ([anotherThing isEqualToString:@"boogers"]) {
    string = @"some characters";
} else {
    string = @"some _other_ characters";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using stringWithFormat: in your answer when you correctly stated in your comments, that it should be used when you have a format string?

Comment: Fair point -- I was copying Erik's original code, but I've edited my post to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The [NSString stringWithFormat:] will initialize a new NSString object for you, basically what you are doing is declaring a new object each time, just set the pointers for your strings as NSSTring *someString, *someOtherString, *allTheStringsYouNeed; and then use any class method to initialize it even @"Characters"; will work correctly as the compiler do it at runtime for you.